# A Dedekind infinite set has a countably infinite proper subset

Tags: set-theory

Set **A** is Dedekind infinite, i.e.
there is a bijective function from **A** onto some proper subset **B** of **A**.

Please prove that **A** has a countably infinite proper subset.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $f : A \to A$ is injective but not onto, fix some $a_0 \in A$ which is not in the range of $f$. Now recursively define $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ for $n \in \omega$. The injectivity of $f$ (and the initial choice of $a_0$) now implies that $a_n \neq a_m$ for $n \neq m$, and so $\{ a_n : n \in \omega \}$ is a countably infinite subset of $A$. (To ensure the *properness* of the subset just omit $a_0$ from the above set.)